# How to encode the ESC character in scala

Tags: scala, escaping

Should be easy. But somehow it is not. And it is difficult to Google because of the double meaning of term «escape».

Anyway I tried the two obvious option (for one who learned C a long time ago) `"\e"` (which is non standard, who would have thought that?) and `"\x1b"` (why does a hex sequence not work?).

I also tried `"\u001b"` — which at least compiles. But still does not give the desired result: An ESC character in the console.

Comment: Maybe it's your console?

Comment: The CMDs create coloured output just fine. But since @thoredge said it works for him I have another look.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that last one, "\u001b", doesn't work? I works at my machine ;-). I use these to to create and reset terminal colors:

```
val cRed = "\u001b[31m"
val cReset = "\u001b[39m"
s"$cRed hello $cReset"
```